# How to read /var/log/wtmp logs in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, elastic-stack

I am trying to read the access log s from `/var/log/wtmp` in elasticsearch

I can read the file when logged into the box by using `last -F /var/log/wtmp`

I have logstash running and sending logs to elasticsearch, here is logstash conf file.

```
input {
  file {
    path => "/var/log/wtmp"
    start_position => "beginning"
  }
}

output {
  elasticsearch {
    host => localhost
    protocol => "http"
    port => "9200"
  }
}
```

what is showing in elasticsearch is

[image]

G

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Once i opened the file using less , i could only see binary data.
Now logstash cant understand this data.
A logstash file like the following should work fine -

```
input { 
  pipe {
    command => "/usr/bin/last -f /var/log/wtmp"
  }
}

output {
    elasticsearch {
    host => localhost
    protocol => "http"
    port => "9200"
    }
}
```

Comment: 100% on the money, Thanks for quick response @Vineeth Mohan

Answer (score 1):

Vineeth's answer is right but the following cleaner config works as well:

```
input { pipe { command => "last" } }
```

`last /var/log/wtmp` and `last` are exactly the same.

---

[utmp, wtmp, btmp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Utmp) are Unix files that keep track of user logins and logouts. They cannot be read directly because they are not regular text files. However, there is the `last` command which displays the information of `/var/log/wtmp` in plain text.

```
$ last --help

Usage:
 last [options] [<username>...] [<tty>...]
```

> I can read the file when logged into the box by using last -F /var/log/wtmp

I doubt that. What the `-F` flag does:

```
-F, --fulltimes      print full login and logout times and dates
```

So, `last -F /var/log/wtmp` will interpret `/var/log/wtmp` as a username and won't print any login information.

What the `-f` flag does:

```
-f, --file <file>    use a specific file instead of /var/log/wtmp
```